# No instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to Integer

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference

In the following code:

```
return new HashSet<>(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(
    SOME_SQL_QUERY_STRING,
    parametersMap,
    (resultSet, rowNum) -> resultSet.getBigDecimal("GETID")
));
```

I'm getting a red line under `(resultSet, rowNum) -> resultSet.getBigDecimal("GETID"))` and the following error : `No instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to Integer`. Can someone please help me and tell why this is happening?

Comment: what type does resultSet contain? it is likely not a number

Comment: you might need to specify the generic param of "query" function: (...) namedParameterJdbcTemplate.<BigDecimal>query(...

Comment: My guess would be the use of lambda results in a different overload of `query()` being used than you expect - check which overload it uses.

Comment: @recurf the resultSet would contain BigDecimal

Comment: @jiriTousek `public <T> List<T> query(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
   throws DataAccessException {

  return query(sql, new MapSqlParameterSource(paramMap), rowMapper);
 }` 
This is the query method getting overloaded. Sorry for bad formatting

Comment: @OvidiuDolha That worked. Can you post it as an answer along with an explanation, so that I can accept it and it will help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that a different (unwanted) overloaded version of the "query" method is inferred (based on the code) and the lambda (Function) given as third parameter is not appropriate for this version of "query".

A way to fix this is to "force" the query function you want by providing the type parameter as such:

```
return new HashSet<>(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.<BigDecimal>query( ...
```

Comment: For future reference this is known as a _type witness_.

Answer (score 1):

> add an explicit casting to your method call

in my case I have

```
<T> Map<String, T> getMap(@NotNull String rootPath, @NotNull Class<T> type)
```

and I used it like

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> x = xmlRegestryFile.getMap("path/to/map/of/string", String.class)
```

but it failed and gave me that error, so I overcomed this error by adding casting

```
x = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) xmlRegestryFile.getMap("my/path", String.class)
```